# Python console printing tab spacing inconsistently

Tags: python

Why does the Python console print tab lengths inconsistently while outputting this expression?

```
print "Slot No.\tRegistration No\tColour"
```

[image]

The tab post `Slot No.` occupies a larger number of screen spaces than the tab post `Registration No`.

When a period is added post `Registration No` leading to the expression:

```
print "Slot No.\tRegistration No.\tColour"
```

the spaces become consistent:

[image]

Comment: Tabs are not consistent in and of themselves. They don't have a fixed size, but rather just "go to" the next tab point.

Comment: Have you checked this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34735246/4788274)?