# How do I get the same spacing between the two columns in the result

Tags: python, formatting, spacing

I just copied this piece of code from a manual but when I wrote it the spacing between the displayed columns gets larger when  kph > 100.

```
# This program converts the speeds 60 kph
# Throug 130 kph ( in 10 kph increments)
# to mph.

START_SPEED = 60              # Starting Speed
END_SPEED = 131               # Ending speed
INCREMENT = 10                # Increment
CONVERSION_FACTOR = 0.6214    # Conversion Factor

# Print the table headings.
print("KPH\tMPH")
print("--------")
for kph in range(60, 131, 10):
    mph = kph * CONVERSION_FACTOR
    print(kph, "\t", format(mph, ".1f"))
```

When I write this code I get:

```
KPH  MPH
--------
60   37.3
70   43.5
80   49.7
90   55.9
100      62.1
110      68.4
120      74.6
130      80.8

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What can I do to make the space between the two columns uniform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the print to this:

```py
for kph in range(60, 131, 10):
    mph = kph * CONVERSION_FACTOR
    print(f'{str(kph):<3s}    {mph:.1f}')
```

The <3s tells python to always keep this value 3 letters short
In regards to why the \t wasn't printed where the numbers where under 100, you can read this explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/34735246/2126254

Answer (score 0):

1. For sting formatting approach, instead of `\t` use `str(kph).ljust(7)` method on printed stings - that will add spaces until string contains specified number of characters.
2. Instead of string formatting I suggest using `pandas.DataFrame` as it has visually nice structure for output data. I would also suggest using `numpy.arange` for the ease of calculation, as it allows for vectorization of operations instead of using elementwise `for-loop`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

kph = np.range(60, 131, 10)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"KPH": kph, 
                             "MPH": kph * CONVERSION_FACTOR})
print(df)
```